# SQL Server trigger not allowing to insert data or modify it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have table which was allowing to enter before I created few new columns in that table. The table calls trigger on UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT which insert data in his log History table I created with the same columns in `History` table.

Now it is not allowing me to insert the data in the table it shows. When I edit in row from the edit option it showing this error.....

```
No row was Updated.
The data in row 1 was not committed 
Error Sources .net SQLClient Data Provider.
Error Message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword where 
Correct the error and retry or press esc to cancel
```

But if I disable the trigger everything works fine.

Trigger

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [magic  ].[magic  ]
ON magic
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS 
    DECLARE @operation CHAR(20) 
    SET @operation= 'N' 

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) 
    BEGIN
        SET @operation = 'Updated'

        INSERT INTO magic.magic_HISTORY
            SELECT *, @operation 
            FROM INSERTED
    END

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        SET @operation = 'Inserted'

        INSERT INTO magic.magic_HISTORY
            SELECT *, @operation 
            FROM INSERTED
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        SET @operation = 'Deleted'

        INSERT INTO magic.magic_HISTORY
            SELECT *, @operation 
            FROM deleted
    END
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the magic_history table? The keyword WHERE does not appear in the code you posted.

Comment: `WHERE` clause syntax error may be in the original query.

Comment: You mention that you have added some new columns, have you also added these columns to magic_History as you are inserting to this table as select * from Inserted

Comment: Yes i add all those same columns to History table as well

Answer (score 1):

If this was my trigger I would change up the logic to make this a LOT simpler. First of all there is no point in auditing the inserted value. You have all the values in the magic table so it is redundant to have a second copy of it. This makes auditing a bit simpler. You only need to worry about the values that were in the table previously.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [magic  ].[magic  ] on magic  
AFTER UPDATE, DELETE AS 

Declare @operation char(20) SET @operation= 'N' 

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) 
    SET @operation = 'Updated'

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    SET @operation = 'Deleted'

INSERT INTO magic.magic_HISTORY
    SELECT  *,@operation FROM deleted
```

Comment: And I'd probably also change the datatype of `@operation` to `varchar(20)` - no point in padding up all those strings with extra spaces on the right side!

Answer (score 0):

When you added columns to magic.magic_HISTORY did you run:

```
ALTER TABLE magic.magic_HISTORY ADD column
```

If so then change:

```
INSERT INTO magic.magic_HISTORY
    SELECT  *,@operation FROM
```

to

```
INSERT INTO magic.magic_HISTORY (column list)
    SELECT  *,@operation FROM
```

Answer (score 0):

What tool/application are you using to do the insert/update into the table?
You can use SQLProfiler to capture the specific SQL being sent to the database. maybe there is a syntax error in the wrapping SQL that calls the trigger.

Also, try adding to your trigger `set nocount on` before the insert into history and then `set nocount off` after.  This will reduce the possibility that the driver is getting confused by "rows effected" messages coming from the trigger.